# Web API Post with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When I call the post web API I'm getting 404 Not found response

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/timesheet/submittimesheet/{fullname}")]
public HttpResponseMessage SubmitTimeSheet([FromUri]string fullname, [FromBody]List<Tracks> list){
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent("Successfully Submitted");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Post (or put) request with uri parameter not working when calling with HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957362/post-or-put-request-with-uri-parameter-not-working-when-calling-with-httpclien) I answered this question just yesterday